# Host Aurelia CLI app and WebApi service on same http server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, aurelia

How do you go about configuring so that `au run` launches and hosts both and Aurelia app and Web API services in the same http server?

The Contact Manager is great and I completely understand why it mocks web services but you can't build a real app like that.

Is there a walkthrough for setting up web services? Event if it just reads some JSON from a file and delivers it, the real question is how to set up with web services running in the same http server to deal with XSS issues.

Failing a full walkthrough how about some guidance on where the node code is that creates the http server instance. `au` and the CLI are wonderful but they hide a lot of important information.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: this is a hard question to answer. get a microsoft server. set up iis to point a virtual directory to your aurelia app, and a application to your web api app. the aurelia and web api parts of this are totally decoupled, and there are LOTS of resources on how to do both of these tasks independently.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis - I tried this option and while I can get it to work I prefer to use `au run --watch` for the BrowserSync goodness so it was necessary to solve the CORS problem per my answer.

Comment: @Larsi - yes and no. There is a resolution that I find satisfactory, described in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is you don't do it.

While theoretically possible, this is both more demanding and less useful than just solving the CORS issues and using a separate server for Web API. This is obvious only if you *know* how to handle CORS at both client and server, and if you knew that it wouldn't cross your mind to ask this question.

To help the lost along this dismally signposted road, here's how to handle CORS for IIS7 MVC/WepApi2 with an Aurelia client on 9000.

### Server

Put this in as a child of the `<system.webServer>` section of the `web.config` file at the root of the Web API project.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

For this example there is a Web API service at http://testserver/DAL3/api/Form with a method bound to post.

Here's a supporting class

```
  public class JsonRequest
  {
    public int UID { get; set; }
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public string Raw { get; set; }
  }
```

And here's what the web service looks like. There's a LINQ2SQL model supporting it which I omit for brevity.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace DAL3.Controllers
{
  public class FormController : ApiController
  {

    // POST: api/Form
    public object Post([FromBody]JsonRequest jsr)
    {
      var T = GetType();
      var M = T.GetMethod(jsr.Command, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
      var parms = new object[] { jsr.UID, jsr.Raw };
      if (M == null) return string.Format("M is null (\"{0}\")",jsr.Command);
      if (parms == null) return "parms is null";

      return M.Invoke(this, parms);
    }

    object Get(int UID, string Raw)
    {
      var dc = new Models.FormsDataContext();
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Raw))
      {
        return dc.Forms.Where(x => x.FormEngine == true);
      }
      else
      {
        var id = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetParams>(Raw).Id;
        return dc.Forms.Where(x => x.FormID == id);
      }
    }
  }
  //this class describes how to parse the parameters for Get
  class GetParams
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
  }
  //if you defined some other method Quux that takes parameters 
  //create a QuuxParams class that matches what JS sends
}
```

All this reflection business lets you specify a method name in `Command` and pass whatever you like to it in `Raw`. UID is a user identifier.

Doing it like this lets you separate CORS compliance from your requests and automates encoding of whatever you put in `Raw`. Which should probably be named `Parameters`, but whatever. Now you know how to put it all together.

### Client

With bash with pwd set to the root of your app:

```
npm i aurelia-http-client --save
```

Then add it to the vendor bundle dependencies in aurelia.json. You don't need an object, just the name in double-quotes with trailing comma as appropriate for valid JSON syntax.

In your code you need to import it.

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';
```

Here's an example of a post to a Web API service called Form in a web app called DAL3 on a box called testserver.

```
let foo = {
  UID: 18974,
  Command: "Get",
  Raw: null
}

let content = "UID=" + foo.UID + "&Command=" + foo.Command + "&Raw=" + JSON.stringify(foo.Raw)

let client = new HttpClient();

let req = client.createRequest("http://testserver/DAL3/api/Form")
 .asPost()
 .withHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 .withContent(content)
 .send()
 .then(res => {
   console.log("Hurrah we have a response!");
 });
```

### Caveats

Any of the following will cause a "preflight" request using the verb OPTIONS and this will result in failure.

- Adding a non-standard header
- Using a content type other than `text/plain` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- Using a verb other than GET or POST

### Encoding the content

The three properties at the root of the object `foo` are URL-encoded and separated by ampersands as shown in the sample code above. Raw could contain an object or even a directed acyclic graph of objects. JSON.stringify correctly processes both. Null will resolve to an empty string but decoding of URL encoding will produce a null so that's fine; the important thing is that the Raw parameter should exist to satisfy Web API signature matching at the other end.